# Quantization of a doughnut field

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

I am trying to understand quantization. There is a big theory in books of QFT, but none of them is telling explicitly what to do in not trivial cases. At least I haven't understood it yet.

I know that there could be a field in doughnut shape.
Here is a key information about it:

[image]

[Source of the photo](https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/386339/1/__soton.ac.uk_ude_personalfiles_users_mw1d13_mydesktop_eprint_FD_OE_final4.pdf)

Can you tell me please, how to quantize it?
At least general steps? Of course, I can compute vector potential $A$ and then try do decompose it is some operators, but I am not sure and intuitively I don't understand what to do.

Comment: This is a macroscopic configuration of the field that still lives in 3+1 flat spacetime: you quantize the usual way that is explained in any QFT book (i.e. as in the QED), assuming I am interpreting your question correctly. What I mean is that "quantizing" is a general procedure that does not depend on the particular configuration of the field.